# Calculate the probability of winning

Tags: probability

> Suppose you are playing a game where you flip a coin to determine who plays first. You know that when you play first, you win the game 60% of the time and when you play the game second, you lose 52% of the time. **A** Find the probability that you win the game?

Let $A = \{ \text{Play first}\}$ and $\overline{A} = \text{Play second}$, let $B = \{ \text{win} \}$

We want $P(B)$.

I know that $P(B | \overline{A}) = 0.48$ and $P(B | A) = 0.6$

**Actual problem:**

I get that $P(B) = P(B | A)P(A)  + P(B | \overline{A}) P(\overline{A}) = 0.6P(A) + 0.48P(\overline{A})$

I'm not sure how to move ahead. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Hint: a coin is flipped to decide who plays first. What does this mean for $\mathrm{P}(A)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$P(A)=\text{chance you get heads at the coin flip}$$

Comment: Ah... I see, winning or not winning, so 0.5?

Comment: I computed, so the total probability is 0.54?

Comment: Yup, that looks right :-)

Answer (score 1):

You flip a coin to decide who plays first and the probability of getting a favourable outcome in the coin toss is $0.5$. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hint -

Probability of getting head = $\frac 12$

And getting tail = $\frac 12$

Then use conditional probability to proceed further.